# shell Script: Sorting files into directories and subdirectories

Tags: shell-script

I routinely write my notes in `markdown` in a complex directory structure like this.

```
~/doc/doc.md
~/doc/math/linearAlgebra/linearAlgebra.md
~/doc/math/linearAlgebra/numericalAnalysis.md
~/doc/linux/tmux/tmux.md
~/doc/linux/newsbeuter/newsbeuter.md
```

This directory structure is ever expanding and each directory has various other files apart from the `*.md` files. I have a shell script that recursively looks for `markdown files` in the parent directory `doc/` and generates `html` and `pdf` files using `pandoc`. I also create a `doc.md` file (through the script) which contains a list of all the `*.md` files. Presently I use,

```
find ~/doc/**/*.md
```

to generate this list. I would like to sort them according to the directory structure for easy perusal like this:

```
math
   linearAlgebra
                          linearAlgebra.md
                          numericalAnalysis.md
linux
   tmux
                          tmux.md
   newsbeuter
                          newsbeuter.md
```

If `fp=/home/user/doc/linux/tmux/tmux.md` is an example full path of a file, then `${${fp%/*.md}#/home/user/doc/}` gives me `linux/tmux`. I can further process it to isolate `linux` and `tmux` etc. But I don't know the algorithm to create the directory structure. I think that this will require use of arrays to store the complete directory structure for each file and then sorting it.

If a shell script already exists to to this, please let me know. Otherwise, pointers on possible algorithm are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is produce a nice formatted output of all `.md` files, `tree` should do exactly what you want:

```
tree -P '*.md' /home/user/doc
```

Add `-A` for pretty lines, it also does interesting things like output to HTML/XML.

Comment: I used `tree --prune -f -R -P "*.md" -H file:///home/user/doc /home/user/doc -o ~/list.html`. Thank you.