# Move all files into subdirectories named after part of file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

I have a directory that contains quite a lot of files with names made up of artirst's name and album e.g.:
[image]

Now the task is to go through each of the files, create a directory named after artist's name and album the file's name, and move the file into that directory.

The final structure should look like this:
[image]

how would I go about doing this with only basic shell commands?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Especially in this type of question, we would have to type in the names without being able to copy and paste from the question, for testing our solutions.

Comment: This would be pretty hard without perfectly uniform filenames.  Also why do your filenames contain special characters! :(

Comment: See also [Move all files into subdirectories named after beginning of file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/295475/80216)  and [shell Script: Sorting files into directories and subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117655/80216).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will mostly do what you want, you are asking for a lot though so let me know if there are any parts you are confused about and I will try to explain them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

song_dir="$HOME/tmp/songs"
out_dir="$HOME/tmp/org_songs"

[[ ! -d "$out_dir" ]] && mkdir -p "$out_dir"

get_artist () {
    local a=($(tr '_' ' ' <<<"$1"))
    for i in "${a[@]}"; do
        if [[ $i =~ artiste.* ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${i#*=}"
            break
        fi
    done
}

get_album () {
    local a=($(tr '_' ' ' <<<"$1"))
    for i in "${a[@]}"; do
        if [[ $i =~ album.* ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${i#*=}"
            break
        fi
    done
}

get_song () {
    local a=($(tr '_' ' ' <<<"$1"))
    for i in "${a[@]}"; do
        if [[ $i =~ song.* ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${i#*=}"
            break
        fi
    done
}

for song in "${song_dir}/"*.mp3; do
    bname=$(basename "$song")
    artist=$(get_artist "$bname")
    album=$(get_album "$bname")
    sname=$(get_song "$bname")
    [[ ! -d "${out_dir}/${artist}/${album}" ]] && mkdir -p "${out_dir}/${artist}/${album}"
    cp "$song" "${out_dir}/${artist}/${album}/${sname}"
done
```

---

**In use:**

Before:

```
$ tree
.
├── script.sh
└── songs
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=meteora_id=02_song=Don't-stay.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=meteora_id=02_song=Session.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=meteora_id=02_song=Somewhere-I-Belong.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=minutes-of-midnight_id=04_song=Bleed-It-Out.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=minutes-of-midnight_id=04_song=Given-Up.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=minutes-of-midnight_id=04_song=Leave-out-All-The-Rest.mp3
    ├── id=01_artiste=eminem_album=recovery_song=cold-wind-blows.mp3
    ├── id=01_artiste=eminem_album=recovery_song=on-fire.mp3
    └── id=01_artiste=eminem_album=recovery_song=talking-2-myself-(feat-kobe).mp3

1 directory, 10 files
```

After:

```
$ tree
.
├── org_songs
│   ├── eminem
│   │   └── recovery
│   │       ├── cold-wind-blows.mp3
│   │       ├── on-fire.mp3
│   │       └── talking-2-myself-(feat-kobe).mp3
│   └── linkin-park
│       ├── meteora
│       │   ├── Don't-stay.mp3
│       │   ├── Session.mp3
│       │   └── Somewhere-I-Belong.mp3
│       └── minutes-of-midnight
│           ├── Bleed-It-Out.mp3
│           ├── Given-Up.mp3
│           └── Leave-out-All-The-Rest.mp3
├── script.sh
└── songs
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=meteora_id=02_song=Don't-stay.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=meteora_id=02_song=Session.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=meteora_id=02_song=Somewhere-I-Belong.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=minutes-of-midnight_id=04_song=Bleed-It-Out.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=minutes-of-midnight_id=04_song=Given-Up.mp3
    ├── artiste=linkin-park_album=minutes-of-midnight_id=04_song=Leave-out-All-The-Rest.mp3
    ├── id=01_artiste=eminem_album=recovery_song=cold-wind-blows.mp3
    ├── id=01_artiste=eminem_album=recovery_song=on-fire.mp3
    └── id=01_artiste=eminem_album=recovery_song=talking-2-myself-(feat-kobe).mp3

7 directories, 19 files
```

---

Also note I'm using `cp` to copy the files instead of `mv` to move them.  I recommend just doing a copy first and then removing the old files afterwards as long as everything worked out right.  Otherwise you risk making a mess of or losing some data.